# Replacing bad performing workers in pool

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

I have a set of actors that are somewhat stateless and perform similar tasks. 
Each of these workers is unreliable and potentially low performing. In my design- I can easily spawn more actors to replace lazy ones.

The performance of an actor is assessed by itself. Is there a way to make the supervisor/actor pool do this assessment, to help decide which workers are slow enough for me to replace? Or is my current strategy "the" right strategy?

Comment: @MartinJames: That's what I'm going to do!

Comment: Easier and a more distributed solution to have workers self-terminate if underperforming on some metric.  That way they won't have to periodically phone home with their status and the worker can finish processing messages in its mailbox (shut down gracefully).  The supervisor will catch the Terminated message and restart.

Comment: @AlexEhrnschwender That's basically what I'm doing now. The only difference is that I don't assign more than one task to worker at one time so that it can terminate without loosing tasks in his mailbox. The thing about that is that I don't feel like it should be worker's responsibility. In real life worker should be fired by boss if he is to lazy. Am I wrong in that feeling?

Comment: I was trying to implement it using BalancingPool, but it doen't work as expected yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198908/replacing-workers-in-balancingpool

Comment: Hmmm.... if they are stateless, can you just use one actor per task? or even  run the task as futures.

Comment: @Julio: Unfortunately they are stageful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to akka myself, so only trying to help, but my attack would be something along the following lines:

- Write your own routing logic, something along the following lines https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.5/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/SmallestMailbox.scala Keep in mind that a new instance is created for every pool, so each instance can store information about how many messages have been processed by each actor so far. In this instance, once you find an actor underperforming, mark it as 'removable' (once it is no longer processing any new messages) in a separate data structure and stop sending further messages.
- Write your own router pool: override createRouterActor https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.3.5/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/RouterConfig.scala:236 to provide your own CustomRouterPoolActor
- Write your CustomRouterPoolActor along the following lines: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/8485cd2ebb46d2fba851c41c03e34436e498c005/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Resizer.scala (See ResizablePoolActor). This actor will have access to your strategy instance. From this strategy instance- remove the routees already marked for removal. Look at ResizablePoolCell to see how to remove actors.

Comment: If you happen to try this- please let me know how it goes. (or how bad it is if you don't! :-))

Comment: it seems that it would be the way I go. However, I'm gonna start implementing boss as a regular actor. And if it will be not enough, will go to implement boss as a pool.

Comment: I did end up with implementing new pool as regular actor. Mainly inspired by  http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2

Answer (score 1):

Question is - why some of your workers perform badly? Is there anything difference between them (I assume not). If not, that maybe some payloads simply require more work the the others - what's the point of terminating them then?

Once we had similar problem - and used [SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.3/index.html#akka.routing.SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic). It basically try to distribute the workload based on mailbox sizes.

Anyway, I would rather try to answer the question - why some of the workers are unstable and perform poorly - because this looks like a biggest problem you are just trying to cover elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Workers have to work with network connections. Thus connections are highly unreliable. I can not fix network issues in any way. That's why I need a software that will dial with that.

Comment: Still - how does terminating a worker/restarting it - solves the problem with external connections?

Comment: Well, I totally agree that "boss" should manage workers, however I would like to try make workers more intelligent somehow if the initiate a connection (allow them to restart it - somehow let them manage their internal state).
Otherwise - I guess writing your own router is the way to go