# Replacing workers in BalancingPool

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using akka [BalancingPool](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.routing.BalancingPool) to distribute tasks over workers. It works pretty well until I add/remove workers in pool. I wanna do because some of workers are unreliable and bad performing. However, balancing pool send all messages only to one worker after replacement.

Here is a scala test for this

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import org.scalatest._
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing._ 
import akka.testkit._

class BalancingPoolSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("BalancingPoolSpec")) with ImplicitSender
  with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override def afterAll {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  val numberOfTestMessages = 5
  val numberOfWorkers = 3
  val pool = system.actorOf(BalancingPool(numberOfWorkers).props(Props[Worker]), "pool")

  def sendMessagesAndCollectStatistic = {
    for (i <- 1 to numberOfTestMessages) pool ! "task"
    (currentRoutes, collectResponces)
  }

  def collectResponces = receiveN(numberOfTestMessages, 10.second).groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length))

  def currentRoutes = {
    pool ! GetRoutees
    val Routees(routees) = expectMsgAnyClassOf(classOf[Routees])
    routees
  }

  def replaceWorkers(oldRoutees: Seq[Routee]) = {
    //Adding new Routees before removing old ones to make it work :)
    for (i <- 1 to numberOfWorkers) pool ! AddRoutee(ActorRefRoutee(system.actorOf(Props[Worker])))
    for (r <- oldRoutees) pool ! RemoveRoutee(r)
    Thread.sleep(500) //Give some time to BalancingPool
  }

  "test" in {
    val (routees1, responces1) = sendMessagesAndCollectStatistic
    replaceWorkers(routees1)
    val (routees2, responces2) = sendMessagesAndCollectStatistic

    assert(responces2.size > 1 , s"""
      Before replacement distribution over ${routees1.size} workers: ${responces1}
      After replacement distribution over ${routees2.size} workers: ${responces2}""")
  } 
}


//For each task worker simulate some work for 1 second and sends back to sender worker's id
object Worker {
  var i = 0
  def newId = synchronized {
    i += 1
    i  
  } 
}

class Worker extends Actor {
  val id = Worker.newId
  def receive = {
    case _ => Thread.sleep(1000); sender ! id
  }
}
```

Failing message

```
1 was not greater than 1
     Before replacement distribution over 3 workers: Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 3 -> 2)
     After replacement distribution over 3 workers: Map(4 -> 5)
```

So, before replacement tasks was distributed over 3 workers, after all 5 tasks went to one worker. Does BalancingPool suppose to handle `AddRoutee/RemoveRoutee` messages in expected way?

Comment: More general question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161763/replacing-bad-performing-workers-in-pool

Comment: The test works for `RoundRobinPool` and `RandomPool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer by Patrik Nordwall in [akka user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/nBnfVmW3YTk):

> The reason is that the BalancingPool use a special dispatcher when it
>   creates the routees. Here you create and add the routees without that.
>   Try this in instead:

```
def replaceWorkers(oldRoutees: Seq[Routee]): Unit = {
    pool ! AdjustPoolSize(-numberOfWorkers)
    pool ! AdjustPoolSize(numberOfWorkers)
    Thread.sleep(500) //Give some time to BalancingPool
  }
```

> However, wouldn't it be better to let the routees throw an exception
>   and thereby restart?